# Form fields being passed with encoded characters in database

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a form that passes all completed fields to a cf component containing the information for inserting each field into the database through a stored procedure. The function in the CFC that contains the information necessary for inserting the database all has the cf_sql_type set with the corresponding fields set with nvarchar. For some reason, whenever the values gathered from what the user inputs on any field has spacing or special characters, it is getting passed into the database in an encoded format.

For example, if spaces are detected, it gets inserted into the database as %20. I need all the form fields to be treated as a string and nothing more. I'm not sure where or what is causing characters to be encoded. I have tried using #canonicalize(fieldname,false,false)# during the insert process on the submission page, but that does not seem to help.

I'm running ColdFusion 10 and using SQL Server 2008 as the database.

Comment: We need to see some code: the form, and what you do with it afterwards, all the way to the DB. Also: what troubleshooting have you done? Is the form data being transmitted correctly between the form and the web server, then onto CF (check the request's post data with dev tools or something)? Is the data correct once CF gets it? Basically... it doesn't yet seem like you've checked whether things are first going wrong. We need that info.

Comment: Are you doign a POST or a GET to pass the data to your CFC? My guess sis you are using a GET and the browser (or maybe JavaScript lib) you are using is encoding those values. If you are using GET you can call `urlDecode()` on those values when calling the stored proc and it should turn the `%20` into a space.

Comment: You're not doing anything crazy like looping over the form scope in `OnRequestStart()` and encoding all existing form variables with `encodeForHTML()`, are you?